# Is it possible to use common fragment generate function globally?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, global

I have common fragment generate function like the following:

```
// Common Fragment generation method
public void generateFragment(String speechString, String buttonString) {

    // Store data to be passed to the fragment in bundle format
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Speech", speechString);
    args.putString("ButtonTitle", buttonString);

    // Instantiate Speech fragment and set arguments
    SpeechFragment newFragment = new SpeechFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    // Dynamically add fragment to view using fragment transaction
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

I made this function to use multiple times in one of my activity.  Now, I found that this function can be used with my another activity.
I also have global variable class but it extends Application.  Yes I know global variable or global function should be declared in a class which extends Application class.
So I can't put the function contains `getSupportFragmentManager()` which connected with activity as global one.

Does anyone know such a function to use between activity?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest you to use one BaseActivity put this function there and make all other activities to extend BaseActivity

Comment: You can only get `FragmentManager` in Activity. This is simple demonstration of OOP, you can create a base activity and then all activities of your app must extend your baseActivity which will have fragmentmanager in that.

Comment: @NavinRajPandey Thanks for your suggestion.  I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm not familiar  with Object Oriented Programing or such kind of theoretical system.  Sorry!!  Will learn them through coding practice...

Comment: "Will learn them through coding practice." => I usually advise not to start learning programming with Android. Basic Java is probably a better idea, because less concepts are used at a time... Then you can move to resource and design management, xml, third party libraries, etc that are part of nearly every app on Android.

Comment: @2Dee Yes I know that I should start from basic theoretical system, I hate that way... ;-)  I like and prefer to code and create something _REAL_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the fragment manager into the method:

```
public static void generateFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String speechString, String buttonString)
```

I would avoid having a `BaseActivity` as others have suggested, because it limits you to what you can extend from: e.g. `FragmentActivity`, `ActionBarActivity`, `ListActivity`, `PreferenceActivity`, e.t.c.
Google "composition over inheritance" to see why this is a bad approach.

Really, what you probably want to do is to split this method up.

In SpeechFragment.java:

```
public static SpeechFragment newInstance(String speechString, String buttonString) {
    // Store data to be passed to the fragment in bundle format
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Speech", speechString);
    args.putString("ButtonTitle", buttonString);

    // Instantiate Speech fragment and set arguments
    SpeechFragment newFragment = new SpeechFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);
    return newFragment;
}
```

The SpeechFragment class will then be responsible on how to initiate itself.
The rest of the method

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, SpeechFragment.newInstance(speechString, buttonString);
transaction.commit();
```

Can then just be part of the classes where this Fragment is used. You then have the flexibility of changing the container id, which FragmentManager to use (could use the child FragmentManager of a Fragment instead), adding / attaching e.t.c instead of replacing - depending on how that fragment needs to be used in the activity.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) is Wikipedia link.  I have read up to Basics ;-)

Comment: Thank you!! I learned that I can put the function to instantiate fragment into fragment class itself. Yes I think it is better that I can change container id or something!! Great!!